# How can we access specific Google Analytics account data using API?

Tags: php, oauth, google-analytics, oauth-2.0

We're developing a web application that allows clients to create and display products.  We'd like to provide our clients with metrics from our Google Analytics account regarding their products in their administration panel.

Unfortunately, the GA API documentation does not shed any light on how to do this; all the example are based around OAuth 2.0 authentication in order to gain access to a **users** GA data instead of the site account.

Is there a way to access Google Analytics data for an account we have access to but the user of the web application does not? I suspect the answer is "no", but if so is there a way we can technically achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to access Google Analytics data for an account we have access to but the user of the web application does not?

Yes, you can use a refresh token. Store the refresh token in a db or secure config file, then use it to show the client stats on their dashboard.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I've gone with and is currently working well.

Answer (score 1):

GAPI can do this for you, the account details go in the code rather than needing a user to auth a GA account: [GAPI - Google Analytics API PHP Interface](http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/)

Comment: I have seen tried this before and have had no luck with it. As far as I can tell this uses older APIs?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own dashboard by accessing the analytics data with an API.
See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/