# not able to get access token from google API

Tags: php, google-api, google-client

When I try to get access token from Google API but I get null

```
        $client = new Google_Client();
            $client->setApplicationName("name app");
            $client->setAccessType('offline');
            $client->setClientId('id client');
            $client->setClientSecret('secret');
            $client->setRedirectUri('redirect url');
            $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly");
        //$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
        $tokens_decoded = json_decode($access_token);
        //$refreshToken = $tokens_decoded->refresh_token;
      if(!$access_token) {
        /**
        * AUCUN TOKEN SAUVE -> IL FAUT REDIRIGER
        * L'UTILISATEUR SUR L'URL $authUrl
        */
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

        die();
      }
```

Please suggest a way to get the same

Comment: You will get access token in redirect URL.

Comment: Please check this answer which has similar issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18264398/3447818

Comment: @md84h also error ... getAccesToken is null :(