# How should I use Google APIs in this scenario?

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In our company we run a number of different websites which are being tracked with Google Analytics (GA). Up to this point we have been using the Login protocol and GData to access GA data to display the data nicely on our custom web application dash boarded which we use for tracking traffic on our sites.

Nowadays Google has Google API Console which lets you track your API usage. We want to take advantage of this service to view howmuch APIs we consume. However from what we can understand it requires us to use OAuth for authentication instead of the username and password we currently use to access the data. We don't like OAuth because it redirects the user to Google for authentication when currently the user has no need to know about where the data is coming from and what credentials are needed.

Is there anyway that we could make Google API Console monitor our usage without having to switch from GData and the Login protocol?

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to the OAuth 2 protocol and use a `refresh token` for offline access. Once you get the `refresh token`, you can save it to a file or database and use that to access the data without an authorization redirect.

See the docs here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#refresh

Also see where there is discussion of using the refresh token: [How can we access specific Google Analytics account data using API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859780/how-can-we-access-specific-google-analytics-account-data-using-api)